# Selecting second child using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>this is some text</p>
    <p>...and this is some other text</p>
</div>
```

How can I retrieve the text from the second paragraph using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector to do this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>>  soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div>
.... <p>this is some text</p>
.... <p>...and this is some other text</p>
.... </div>""", "html.parser")

>>>  soup.select('div > p')[1].get_text(strip=True)
     '...and this is some other text'
```

Comment: Can't be more pythonic!

Comment: @hashcode55  how about: `soup.select_one('div > p:nth-of-type(2)').get_text(strip=True)`?

Comment: @alecxe How can I get the following html element as I am getting it using js with beautifulsoup in python-- document.querySelector('body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(11) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(5) > input[type="hidden"]:nth-child(1)').getAttribute("name")

Comment: What if there is a div inside of a div, rather than a p tag? Would you leave the select function empty?

Answer (score 17):

You can use *nth-of-type*:

```
h = """<div>
    <p>this is some text</p>
    <p>...and this is some other text</p>
</div>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

print(soup.select_one("div p:nth-of-type(2)").text)
```

Comment: How can I get the following html element as I am getting it using js with beautifulsoup in python-- document.querySelector('body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(11) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(5) > input[type="hidden"]:nth-child(1)').getAttribute("name")

Answer (score 2):

```
secondp = [div.find('p') for div in soup.find('div')]

In : secondp[1].text

Out : Your text
```

Or you can use the `findChildren` directly -

```
div_ = soup.find('div').findChildren()
for i, child in enumerate(div_):
    if i == 1:
         print child.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """\
<div>
    <p>this is some text</p>
    <p>...and this is some other text</p>
</div>
"""

soup = Soup(html)
soup.find('p')[1].text
```

Which would output:

> '...and this is some other text'