# How can I select every nth child in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In my table below I have scraped Items 1-4 and stored them in a variable called headings.

I would also like to select Values 1-4 and store them in a variable called columns, is there anyway to select every second . Something like

```
columns = boxinfo.find_all("td").nthChild(2)
```

**Table structure I am scraping from**

```
<div class="box1">

<table class="table1">

<tr><td class="label">Item1</td><td>Value1</td></tr>

<tr><td class="label">Item2</td><td>Value2</td></tr>

<tr><td class="label">Item3</td><td>Value3</td></tr>

<tr><td class="label">Item4</td><td>Value4</td></tr>

</table>

</div>
```

**Code**

```
#Find our information
boxinfo = soup.find("div", {"id": "box1"})
headings = boxinfo.find_all("td", {"class": "label"})
columns = boxinfo.find_all("td").nthChild(2) #This does not work :(
```

Comment: pure beautiful soup you can't, though you can add filter functions to your searches. but the easiest is something like `columns = [column for i, column in enumerate(boxinfo.find_all("td")) if i%2 == 1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting second child in beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233838/selecting-second-child-in-beautiful-soup)

Comment: @bobrobbob How can I get the following html element as I am getting it using js with beautifulsoup in python-- document.querySelector('body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(11) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(5) > input[type="hidden"]:nth-child(1)').getAttribute("name")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are trying to extract all of the values, then you would let BeautifulSoup return all of the items and Python can then filter the values you want. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="box1">
<table class="table1">
<tr><td class="label">Item1</td><td>Value1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Item2</td><td>Value2</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Item3</td><td>Value3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Item4</td><td>Value4</td></tr>
</table>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("div", class_="box1")
values = []

for tr in div.find_all('tr'):
    values.append(tr.find_all("td")[1].text)

print(values)
```

Giving you a list of values:

```
['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4']
```

Or if you want a list of containing all of the data as columns:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("div", class_="box1")
columns = []

for tr in div.find_all('tr'):
    columns.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all("td")])

columns = list(zip(*columns))    

print(columns)
print(columns[1])  # display the 2nd column
```

Giving you:

```
[('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4'), ('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4')]
('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4')
```

`list(zip(*columns))` is a way of transposing a list of rows into a list of columns.

Comment: @Martin Evans How can I get the following html element as I am getting it using js with beautifulsoup in python-- document.querySelector('body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(11) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(5) > input[type="hidden"]:nth-child(1)').getAttribute("name")

Comment: @dpkrai96, it would be easier if you create a new question with some code to show the problem. You can then add a comment below your question with my name and I'll see it.

Comment: @Martin Evans  This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764574/unable-to-select-html-element-using-beautifulsoup-css-selector-while-able-to-ge