# Unable to select HTML element using BeautifulSoup CSS-selector but was able to get the element in JS using CSS-selectors

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am using Python and the BeautfulSoup HTML parser to select HTML elements. However, I'm unable to get this working.

```
response = requests_session.post(login_url, headers=headers, data=data_credentials) # log in to the requests Session so that you can reuse it

search_url= 'https://www.website.com/search.php'
p_id='342953'

response = requests_session.get(search_url,headers=headers, params={'query':p_id,'type':'p'})
redirected_urls=response.url
th_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
trx_ht =th_soup.select("body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(11) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(5) > input[type='hidden']:nth-child(1)")
```

Comment: What's `website.com/search.php`? I'm getting a 404 on that and presume it's a dummy URL. Glaring omissions aside, I doubt this can be debugged without looking at the DOM you're trying to scrape.

Comment: @ggorlen That is not real one.I am intentionally using a dummy url. Actual one I have in the actual code.

Comment: @ggorlen But the selector are actual one and it is working in Java Script code.

Comment: OK, but how can I debug your code without the DOM? Also, best not to roll back on formatting edits that clearly improve the post.

Comment: @ggorlen is right. Not much anyone can do if you don't provide the actual code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Make sure you are using Beautiful Soup 4.7+. CSS selectors support before 4.7 did not work as expected, for instnace, `:nth-child` did not behave correctly according to the specification. Aside from that, without knowing the actual structure of the HTML, no one can tell if you are correctly or incorrectly accessing elements.

Comment: please see [mcve]

Comment: @dpkrai96, as an alternative you could use some `find()` calls rather than a single select. Without the URL, or a copy of the HTML it will not be possible to help further. You could use a service like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to upload the whole HTML to and then post a link to it here.

Comment: @Martin Evans I have tried using find(). Please find the paste bin link. 
https://pastebin.com/sm7iXcUq

Comment: Great, I can see the HTML. Which elements are you trying to extract using that select? i.e. what should the output be?

Comment: I am trying to get that is accessible using js  css-selectors like this. document.querySelector('body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(11) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(5) > input[type='hidden']).getAttreibute('name');

Comment: What result does that give you? For example are you trying to extract say the total `$5.23` ?  Could you tell me the line number in the HTML that you are trying to access?

Comment: @Martin Evans I am getting this "qtyb-52843099" and selector is below

document.querySelector('body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(11) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(5) > input[type="hidden"]:nth-child(1)').getAttribute("name")

Comment: Does the `name` attribute always start `qtyb-`?

Comment: No but some of the cases

Answer (score 1):

From the HTML you have given in your pastebin, the hidden input could be located using a `.find_all()` call with specific attributes. If the field you want always starts `qtyb-`, you can use a regular expression with BeautifulSoup to find all matching elements as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Read the HTML in from a file (normally requests is used)

with open('sm7iXcUq.html', encoding='utf-8') as f_html:
    html = f_html.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all('input', attrs={'type' : 'hidden', 'name' : re.compile('qtyb-.*')}):
    print(i)
```

For the HTML you have given, this would return one element as follows:

```html
<input name="qtyb-52843099" type="hidden" value="1"/>
```

The value for `name` can be obtained using:

```
i['name']
```

This approach would give you all elements with the matching `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also use the following? This assumes `input[value=1][name]` is a constant across sources

```
soup.select_one('input[value=1][name]')['name']
```